# Getting a random item from a ArrayList<String>

Tags: java

I want to select a random string from my ArrayList and then print that string. 
here is my code:

```
 public class Operator {

Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
public void CreateArrayList() {
     myArray.add("add");
     myArray.add("subtract");
     myArray.add("multiply");
     myArray.add("divide");
     myArray.add("remainder");
     myArray.add("greaterthan");
     myArray.add("lessthan");
     myArray.add("max");
     myArray.add("min");
     myArray.add("power");
     try {
            FileReader inFile = new FileReader("data/numbers2.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);

            scanner.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
{

}

public void showOperations() {
    int x = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    int y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    int z = rand.nextInt(10);
    System.out.println(x+" "+ myArray.get( z )+" "+ y );
    }
}
```

The output should be for example "3 add 4". However, ever time I run the code, I get

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) at hw2p2.Operator.showOperations(Operator.java:42) at hw2p2.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:9)`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at hw2p2.Operator.showOperations(Operator.java:42)
 at hw2p2.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:9)

Comment: Also, show your main method and code as a [mcve]

Comment: You never called `CreateArrayList()`....

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  Operator op = new Operator();
  op.showOperations();
 }

}

Comment: `int z = rand.nextInt(10);` should be `int z = rand.nextInt(myArray.size());`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include large  code and errors . The comments should not be used for that

Comment: Call CreateArrayList() before calling showOperations() method.

Comment: Ok, I got. Thanks everyone

Comment: If you don't like to override comments like "// TODO Auto-generated method stub", deactivate them in the IDE, because I guess, `Operator op = new Operator(); op.showOperations();` was not auto generated, so the comment is a lie.

Comment: the standard convention is to name methods in camelCase fashion, so I took the liberty of renaming your createArrayList() method

Answer (score 1):

`rand.nextInt(10);` gets a random number with no respect to the content of your list.

You need to pass the size of the list there, not literally `10` using `myArray.size()`

Secondly, if you want your code to do anything other than choose a random element from an empty list, you'll need to call that other method

<sub>It's a list, not an array</sub>

Comment: Well, that would be useful, if the size of that list would change. Since there are exactly 10 elements, he already passes the size of the list. Telling him, he needs to pass the size of the list is wrong and in contradiction to the advice, to not pass 10, which is the size of the list. It's more robust against experiments - I don't dispute that. :)

Comment: The size of the list is only 10 if the add methods were actually ran, so therefore the size of the list does change

Comment: No. `myArray.size ()` doesn't heal the problem. If the problem is healed (calling the array initializing code), the part you we don't like needs not to be fixed. Fixing it would be nice, but is for such fire-and-forget-code overengineering. It's even a theorem prover, if the code is run often enough (The theorem here is: The list contains 10 elements).

Answer (score 0):

You never actually created the arrayList, so when you call the array in your showoperations method, it ends up trying to do the operations on an empty array. In addition, I tweaked your calculation for z so that it will give you a number no matter the sizeof the arrayList.

```
    import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Operator {

Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public void createArrayList() {
     myArray.add("add");
 myArray.add("subtract");
 myArray.add("multiply");
 myArray.add("divide");
 myArray.add("remainder");
 myArray.add("greaterthan");
 myArray.add("lessthan");
 myArray.add("max");
 myArray.add("min");
 myArray.add("power");
 try {
        FileReader inFile = new FileReader("data/numbers2.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);

            scanner.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

public void showOperations() {
    createArrayList();
    int x = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    int y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    int z = rand.nextInt(myArray.size());
    System.out.println(x+" "+ myArray.get( z )+" "+ y );
    }
}
```